# How to sort array in JSON to get value of specific index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Hi I am very new to JSON and API, and working on an API in which I am getting value in an array eg.

```
{
   id: 0,
   text: "one"
}
{
   id: 1,
   text: "two"
}
{
   id: 2,
   text: "three"
}
```

I want the value of only of an array where `id=0` and i don't know how to sort array in JSON to achieve this, I used ajax to fetch this value

```
async function getDataFromId() {
    let url = 'API_URL';
    let Qid = 1;
    let result;
    try {
        result = await jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
        });
        result = result.sort((a, b) => a.id- b.id);
        console.log(result)
    }catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to sort it if you only want the value where `id=0`? Wouldn't filter it be enough?

Comment: @Turtlean I am sorry this is very noob thing but, how to filter?

Comment: [What is JSON anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: Try this : `var new_array = result.filter(function(i){return i.id == 0})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the above answers are good but you are using a variable `Qid`

```
result = result.filter(function(i){return i.id === Qid});
console.log(resulr)
```

You don't need to sort it you can filter this, That will be more easy stuff for your work

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to sort the array to get object where id == 0.
Use Array#find to find you desire object.

```js
let myObject = myArr.find((_o)=>_o.id === 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```js
if(result){
  resultSorted = result.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  resultFiltered = result.filter(x => x.id == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want the value of only of an array where id=0

You're properly sorting the result in `ascendant order` according to their ID's, so the only thing left is creating an array that only contains the first element:

```js
result = result.sort((a, b) => a.id- b.id)
console.log([result[0])
```

You can take advantage of the condition that you are after to `filter` the array. In this case: `id === 0`. That will remove the elements that doesn't match the condition (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
result = result.filter((a) => a.id === 0)
console.log(result)
```

Bear in mind that `sorting` an array is more expensive that just `filtering` it, so if you're only interested in keeping the one with `id === 0` I'd definitely go for the `filter` option